# Didn't manage to locate region names correctly in stackplot

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook

What I want:

[Desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbIom.png)

What I create:

[Created plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZeuk.png)

There are two different issue. Firstly, I didn't manage to locate region names correctly.
Second, Why does the bottom data (blue one) is different from stack pattern?

My code:

```
    import pandas as pd #import pandas library
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplot pyplot to use plot functions

    DataFrame = pd.read_csv("xxx.csv") 

    regionsOfData = ['Asia (UN)', 'Africa (UN)', 'Latin America and the Caribbean (UN)', 'Europe (UN)', 'Northern America (UN)'] #region of data is determined according to requirement of final document
    
    filterByEntity = DataFrame[DataFrame['Entity'].isin(regionsOfData)] 
    
    pivotData = filterByEntity.pivot(index='Year', columns='Entity', values='Births - Sex: all - Age: all - Variant: estimates') 

    createdStackPlot = plt.stackplot(pivotData.index, pivotData.values.T) 

    for i, regionsOfData in enumerate(regionsOfData): 
        color = createdStackPlot[i].get_facecolor()[0] 
        plt.text(2021, pivotData[regionsOfData].iloc[-1], regionsOfData, color=color, fontsize=10, va='center', ha='center') 

    plt.yticks([0, 20e6, 40e6, 60e6, 80e6, 100e6, 120e6, 140e6], ['0 million', '20 million', '40 million', '60 million', '80 million', '100 million', '120 million', '140 million']) 

    plt.title('annual number of births by region', color='red') 
    
    plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.4) 
    
    plt.gca().spines['left'].set_visible(False) 
    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False) 
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False) 
    
    plt.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False) 
    
    plt.show() #show the final plot
```

I create a pivot table from csv file (related column), I created a stackplot from this pivot table. I don't manage to do that.

Comment: Any idea? I have located the labels according to their location. But the bottom data is still freakening